# Get all the parent AD groups a user belongs to

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I want to get all the Active Directory groups in which a particular user is a member.

I do have the script to get all the immediate AD groups for a user (see codes below).

However, how do I get all the parent groups for each of the immediate AD groups the user belongs to?

e.g. I am directly part of the AD group called `IT Team Managers`. This group is member of a parent group called `IT Team National` etc. How do I get this parent group from my code?

Thanks so much in advance!

```
DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
ouSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=" + username + "))";

//ouSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");
ouSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
ouSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

SearchResult allOUS = ouSearch.FindOne();

//foreach (string g in allOUS.Properties["memberOf"])
{
    equalsIndex = g.IndexOf("=", 1);
    commaIndex = g.IndexOf(",", 1);

    if (equalsIndex == -1)
    {
       return null;
    }

    groupNames.Append(g.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
    groupNames.Append(",");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // get the "authorization groups" the user is a member of - recursively
   var authGroups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

   // iterate over groups
   foreach(Principal p in authGroups)
   {
      // do something with groups ....       
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: thank you so much for your response. it works - however when i run it, it is SOOOOOO slow in returning ~100 AD groups...almost 1 minute...is there any way to speed up or how do i refine/filter the groups so it doesn't return so many groups?